# Counting the number of odd, even, max and the total number of integers entered in User Input.

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am fairly new to C++ and I have been completely stuck on what to do for the last 2 hours. I can only use iostream library. 
One of the requirements is to cancel the loop when 0 is typed in, and then once the loop is stopped I need to have it display the amount of even numbers, odd numbers, max number and total number of integers that were entered.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    int number, 
    integer, 
    even = 0, 
    odd = 0, 
    max, 
    total;

do {
    cout << "Type an integer (type 0 to stop):";
    cin >> number;
}
    while (number != 0);
{
if (number % 2 == 0) 
    even++;
else
    odd++;
}
cout << "# of evens = " << even; 
cout << "# of odds = " << odd; 
    cout << "max = ";
    cout << "number of integers entered is ";

return 0;
```

}

Comment: You need an array with a variable length and you can't use `<vector>`? Go punch your teacher!

Comment: Your `do` `while` is too short. It does not allow to manage `number`. Don't forget to stop if `number == 0`.

Comment: Where do you want to store your values? Does the user have a limited number of inputs? Have you learnt about arrays?

Comment: You don't need to store all the values. Just move your check for even/odd into the loop (if the number is valid).

Comment: Don't punch your teacher. It's bad for the grades. Just remember for later that you are travelling paths oft taken and there are canned solutions for most of them. Recommend indenting your code better. It makes mistakes like the `do{}while{}` a bit easier to spot.

Comment: There is no gain in punching your teacher since no vector or array is even needed to complete the exercise.   Put the logic to keep track of number of odds, evens, max, and total in the loop body, and print the values after the loop finishes.

Answer (score 4):

The requirements of counting even and odd numbers, max number and number of  numbers do not require to store the value entered by the user.  So you need to do all this in the loop.

The `do .. while` syntax is as follows:

```
do { 
    // all the loop operations go here 
} while (condition);  
// here the loop is over !!! it's executed AFTER, when condition is false
```

The syntax that you've used doesn't work as you think:

```
do { 
    // all the loop operations go here 
} while (condition);     // semi-column means "end of statement"
{
   // ...this is a block of statements.  It's independent of the while 
   // so it will still only be executed when the loop is over.  
}
```

So unfortunately, your `do..while` loop only has input and output.  The  processing of the number is currently done outside the loop.  So it will be performed only once : when user entered 0.

Rework your loop:

```
do {
    cout << "Type an integer (type 0 to stop):";
    cin >> number;
    if (number !=0 ) {
        // .. put all your processing and counting here
    }
} while (number != 0);
```

As you learn IT and maybe one day program the flight computer of a plane that I might take, I prefer to let you finish your exercise within the loop, to be sure that you have a full understanding f what you're supposed to know.

Answer (score 1):

While this type of question generally doesn't belong on SO, you gave it a shot and demonstrated some fixable problems:

1. Unless you're storing them in an array (which, from what I've read, is unnecessary), you need to perform your number logic inside the loop. Otherwise it will only be performed on the last number entered.
2. Given that, your loop structure would become complicated, because logic would be performed on the last 0. I would use a normal while loop and use "break" if the number entered was zero before you perform logic.
3. Remember that cout does not automatically insert newlines.
4. To create a count, just start at zero and increase by one each time you enter in a number. If you stuck with the original do-while and had zero considered, you would have to decrease by 1 the count and number of evens.
5. To store the max, again, you don't have to store all numbers entered. All you have to do is keep track of the current maximum. Set it to a number less than the minimum considered number and create a similar condition.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

SPOIL (don't read if you don't want the solution) (c-like):

```
#include <iostream>

struct stats {
    int max;
    int total;
    unsigned int counter;
    unsigned int even;
    unsigned int odd;
};

static void display(struct stats const &stats) {
    std::cout << "counter = " << stats.counter << '\n';
    std::cout << "even = " << stats.even << '\n'; 
    std::cout << "odd = " << stats.odd << '\n'; 
    std::cout << "max = " << stats.max << '\n';
    std::cout << "total = " << stats.total << '\n';
}

static int ask_number(void) {
    int number;
    std::cout << "Type an integer (type 0 to stop):";
    std::cin >> number;
    return number;
}

static void do_stats(int const number, struct stats &stats) {
    if (number % 2 == 0) {
        stats.even++;
    }
    else {
        stats.odd++;
    }
    stats.total += number;
    stats.counter++;
    if (number > stats.max) {
        stats.max = number;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int number = ask_number();  
    struct stats stats = {number, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    while (number != 0) {
        do_stats(number, stats);
        number = ask_number();
    }

    display(stats);

    return 0;
}
```

SPOIL (don't read if you don't want the solution) (true cpp):

```
#include <iostream>

class Number {
public:
    static int ask(std::ostream &os, std::istream &is) {
        int number;
        os << "Type an integer (type 0 to stop):";
        is >> number;
        return number;
    }
    void ask_and_replace(std::ostream &os, std::istream &is) {
        number = ask(os, is);
    }
    Number(std::ostream &os, std::istream &is) :
        number(ask(os, is))
    {
    }
public:
    int number;
};

class Stats {
public:
    Stats(int max) :
        max(max),
        total(0),
        counter(0),
        even(0),
        odd(0)
    {
    }

private:
    int max;
    int total;
    unsigned int counter;
    unsigned int even;
    unsigned int odd;

public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Stats const &stats);
    void run(int const number) {
        if (number % 2 == 0) {
            even++;
        }
        else {
            odd++;
        }
        total += number;
        counter++;
        if (number > max) {
            max = number;
        }
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Stats const &stats)
{
    os << "counter = " << stats.counter << '\n';
    os << "even = " << stats.even << '\n'; 
    os << "odd = " << stats.odd << '\n'; 
    os << "max = " << stats.max << '\n';
    os << "total = " << stats.total << '\n';
    return os;
}

int main(void) {
    Number number(std::cout, std::cin);
    Stats stats(number.number);

    while (number.number != 0) {
        stats.run(number.number);
        number.ask_and_replace(std::cout, std::cin);
    }

    std::cout << stats;

    return 0;
}
```